# Multi Domain SSL Certification - 500 Domains

Tags: ssl

I have some questions about Multi Domain SSL Certifiations that I'm struggling to find answers to on the Net.

What options are there for a large number of Domains (say 500) to run under one SSL Cert?

Does anyone know any that cater for a large number like 500 Domains?

If not what are the larger Multi Domain SSL Certs avaliable? 200?

Can domain names be switched on the fly (eg: add one or remove one) or must they be setup at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put multiple domains into a single certificate you have to use subject alternative names. While there is in theory no limit on how many SAN you can use (ok, there is a size limit of the certificate) in reality CAs set the limit to about 100 (maybe more if you pay more). To reduce the number of SAN you can use multiple wildcard domains (*.example.com). If this still does not help you can use multiple certificates on the same IP if client and server support SNI (Server Name Indication), all current browsers should support this and most current web servers.